# Spring AOP: Can't convert type from >classname< to pointcut

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

I'm working on a Spring MVC web application and I'm trying to set up an AOP wrapper for a specific method. I've got the following in `aop-config.xml`:

```
<bean name="callCatcher" class="com.business.project.aop.callCatcher"/>

<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
    <aop:pointcut expression="execution(* com.business.project.util.className.methodName(..))" id="catchCall"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="callCatcher"  pointcut-ref="catchCall"/>
</aop:config>
```

The `proxy-target-class="true"` was added after finding similar questions here on SO where that was suggested but it doesn't seem to have done anything for my situation.

`aop-config.xml` is included in my `servlet-config.xml`:

```
<import resource="aop-config.xml"/>
```

When I attempt to deploy this I'm getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.business.project.util.className' to required type 'org.springframework.aop.Pointcut' for property 'pointcut'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.business.project.util.className] to required type [org.springframework.aop.Pointcut] for property 'pointcut': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:463)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:494)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:488)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1433)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 37 more
```

The class that I'm trying to intercept is being auto-wired as a property on the class that's using it.. so I'm wondering if that's part of the problem. It's nothing too special:

```
public class className implements ApplicationContextAware {...}
```

The method that I'm trying to intercept is public.

I'm not sure what else to include. I've googled the exception, the proxying, checked the pointcut expression. Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

I included cglib in the project's ivy configuration and set up the aop-config as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>

    <bean name="callCatcher" class="com.business.project.aop.EditorActionLogger"/>

    <aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
        <aop:pointcut expression="execution(* com.business.project.util.className.methodNAme(..))" id="callCatcher"/>
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="editorActionLogger"  pointcut-ref="timeslotReloader"/>
    </aop:config>
</beans>
```

Still getting the same exception.

Comment: I... really don't know. I don't think so; We use Ivy for dependency management and I checked the config file and don't see anything for cglib.

Comment: If you force cglib proxying rather than `Spring` it should be fine. Can you add the dependency for ivy [see here](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.net.sf.cglib&version=2.2.0)?

Comment: I checked our ivy repo and we have cglib 2.1.3; I added that as a dependency and redeployed with the aop-config as it is in the question and it gave me the same error. Is there something else I need to do to force it to use cglib rather than Spring?

Comment: Try adding `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>` from [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying)

Comment: Added it; same exception. I put the entire contents of the aop-config into the question.

Comment: Had a similar problem before with proxy based AOP and solved it using aspectj weaving instead. This should work for you although it should also be possible to get AOP working with cglib. Havent used it enough to guide you further

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help and the hint. I'll look into aspectj weaving.

Comment: I would look at trying to get cglib working first though. See this [related post](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?91868-Spring-AOP-proxying-with-CGLIB-not-working)

Comment: Try to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850536/enabling-aop-breaks-my-dependency-injection-for-a-factory-bean-that-takes-a-stri

Comment: I don't think that question's going to be helpful. The answer says "It works fine with a simple `execution()` designator though"... but that's what I'm using. Also the biggest difference I see between my issue and all the other ones I find is that in their exception it says $Proxy## but mine doesn't..

Comment: man I think you have to put 

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>

in servlet-config.xml not aop-config.xml to be in same context of bean you want to use AOP on it className

Answer (score 2):

man I think you have to put

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

in servlet-config.xml not aop-config.xml to be in same context of bean you want to use AOP on it className

Comment: The aop-config is imported into the servlet-config with: `<import resource="aop-config.xml"/>`. I'll try putting it directly into the servlet-config in a little while though and let you know if it works.